# jQuery $.ajax passes null value to MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

i've been struggling with this problem for quite some time. I've followed all suggestions provided in similar problems but without success.

As the title says, data passed by my `$.ajax` is not received by my controller.

jQuery:

```
var data = {
    id: id,
    app: app
};


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Utility/FetchTransactionLog",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json;",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                h.resultDiv.html(data);
            }
            else {
                h.resultDiv.html("");
                alert("No Log Found");
            }
        }
    });
```

Controller:

```
//id and app receives null values
public ActionResult FetchTransactionLog(string id,string app) {
    UtilityModels util = new UtilityModels(app);
    List<ResultModel> result = util.FetchTransactionLog(id);
    return View("LogResult", result);            
}
```

Route in Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Utility", action = "Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
     "FetchLog",
     "Utility/FetchTransactionLog/{id}/{app}",
     new { controller = "Utility", action = "FetchTransactionLog", id = "", app = "" } // Parameter defaults
 );
```

What am i doing wrong?

**Update**

The following works as suggested by Samich:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Utility/FetchTransactionLog/" + id + "/" + app,
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json;",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    h.resultDiv.html(data);
                }
                else {
                    h.resultDiv.html("");
                    alert("No Log Found");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: try just to append your `id` and `app` to your url as you specified in the routes `/Utility/FetchTransactionLog/{id}/{app}`

Comment: @Samich, it works!! However, it still confuses me as to why my earlier approach didn't work?

Comment: Probably because your routing expects values in query string and doesn't find it there, so the default values provided from the routing registration

Comment: And probably you don't need to provide empty data `data: "{}",` at all

Comment: Thanks @Samich, you are right, i don't need the empty data parameter as well so i've removed it. Can you post your suggestion in the answer segment so that i can mark is as an answer?

Comment: Done. I'm gald that we solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try just to append your id and app to your url as you specified in the routes `/Utility/FetchTransactionLog/{id}/{app}`

Probably because your routing expects values in query string and doesn't find it there, so the default values provided from the routing registration

Answer (score 1):

Why do you do JSON.stringify your data? You should just pass the object as it is, like

```
data: data,
```

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) says flat out that if you pass in an object, it will be converted to a string automatically. By passing in a *string* that *contains* JSON, you are confusing jQuery and it ends up passing garbage data to ASP (using your browser's developer tools to inspect the request would have immediately made this apparent).

Comment: Sorry @Jon but it still receives null values. It seems to be a problem with routing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` shouldn't be a JSON string, just leave it as a Javascript object. jQuery will convert this to POST parameters, which your controller can then read.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Utility/FetchTransactionLog",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            h.resultDiv.html(data);
        }
        else {
            h.resultDiv.html("");
            alert("No Log Found");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but parameter still receives null values.

Comment: Because your routes are routing for `Utility/FetchTransactionLog/{id}/{app}`, not for a POST request.

Comment: So, how do you normally handle an ajax post?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this at the moment but try changing -

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

to

```
data: data,
```

`JSON.stringify` will format you data in a way that prevents jQuery posting it correctly. If you pass a normal object everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Utility/FetchTransactionLog",
    data: { id: id, app: app },
    contentType: "application/json;",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            h.resultDiv.html(data);
        }
        else {
            h.resultDiv.html("");
            alert("No Log Found");
        }
    }
});
```